# how escape sleep mode on network, Wake-on-LAN?

Tags: windows, rdp, wake-on-lan

I have computer about 4-years old with microsoft windows server 2008 r2 operating system. It rans a web and rdp-server. i want this computer wake up if i want to connect to it remotely. How can i do that? I found some articles about wake on lan and magic packets, but maybe more  flexible ways exist, so i can wake my server from the internet. hope for your help

Comment: What do you mean by wake up? If this is running as a web server, is it going to sleep/hibernate?

Comment: Try serverfault instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two routes, software or hardware:

1. Software - Use Wake On Lan as you have mentioned:

[SourceForge WOL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/aquilawol/)

1. Hardware - Buy a remote enabled KVM (search for KVM over IP).

The software is free and will work if your network card supports it, the hardware is expensive...your choice.

This is a bit unusual as servers aren't normally allowed to sleep. You could always go into power management and prevent the server going into sleep in the first place.

Comment: i downloaded this program, but dont find where is the server configuration like in manual...
And i'm guess i cant use this program through the web

Comment: To wake up over the Internet, you'll need to set up your router to forward a port to the server; the default for WOL is 7 but I guess you can use whatever you like.  You then use your external IP address and the server's MAC address.

Comment: i have already set up router, i dont understand how to setup the program. There are screens in manual of a server configuration window, but i cant find this window in program. It only suggests to add other computers and control them, but not the computer i installed this program to.

Comment: You use the program to send a magic packet to the server, using the IP address of your router and the MAC address of the server. You don't install it on the server. Try this link, there are links to mopre resources on this page: http://www.ezlan.net/WOL.html You already have the magic packet utility - sourceforge wol.